# What is this hole above the intake of engines of Mil helicopters?

Tags: helicopter, feature-identification

Almost all the helicopters designed and manufactured by Mil have a hole above the intake. e.g.

[image: image1]

What is it for? APU? Other helicopters made by this company:

[image: image2]

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This link](http://www.aviastar.org/helicopters_eng/mi-26.php) claims it's the central oil cooler intake for the Mi-26.

Answer (score 0):

This is lubrication oil cooler.
APU intake is on right side and APU exhaust is on left side(small APU exhaust opening behind engine exhaust in first pic and third pic )